# Installing Packages every time you create a node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, meanjs

I am going through a MEAN  stack development PDF .

Every Time i need to create a new API , they ask to add required packages in `packages.json` file and run `npm install`.

Example :

```
 {
  "name": "node-api",
   "main": "server.js",
   "dependencies": {
   "morgan": "~1.5.0",
   "express": "~4.10.3",
   "body-parser": "~1.9.3",
   "mongoose": "~3.8.19",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3"
  }
 }
```

then do  in terminal:

```
npm install
```

So if I create new API say API2 then again i need to do the same and all the packages are downloaded again for node_modules:

My Question is: can't we download and store these packages locally and use whenever we require them, just like we do in Python or C++, instead of Downloading every time again.

Comment: You can simply copy the `node_modules` folder to your disk storage, after the first `npm install` and every subsequent `npm install` (when you update versions or dependencies).

Comment: and then if i add new packages and do npm install , will it download packages selectively that at not available ?

Answer (score 1):

you can install package globaly with the `g` flag. E.g : `npm install -g <package_name>`.
if you want to install a package globaly with a specific version : `npm install -g <package_name>@<version>`.

But you have to understand that each applications need a specific version of a package that why it's very useful to have the ability to install the right pacakge with a version compatible to run it. In python, we use for example virtualenv.

For example, an application A can maybe have 3 packages in common that application B have but, the version of these packages are not the same because packages version of A applications are not comptatible to run the B application. That why, you have to install all packages of each apps with `npm install`.

Comment: This is a BAD BAD practice!

Comment: This is what i'm said. Please read my anwser... I just explain how to install a package globaly and after why it's important to don't do that...

Answer (score 0):

Each application has a "packages.json" file that list all dependencis so i think smartsn123 is right it's better to have a global repository instead of creating a local one for each app and use "packages.json" to select from global repo.
it gets worse when you notice that some dependencies have a node_modules folder in them.